# Netbeans: separate indentation settings for XML

Tags: netbeans, indentation

(for Netbeans 8.0)

Netbeans has separate indentation settings under **Options->Editor->Formatting** for some languages but not others. I'd like to indent most languages by 4 spaces, but XML by 2 spaces. There is an "HTML" language setting but it does not affect XML formatting.

Is there a way to add XML as a language or make the HTML settings apply to .xml files, or otherwise accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to have the same preference. A workaround I use is to set the default to two spaces and then Java to 4.

This has the advantage of picking up other xml like files which have different extensions, and it covers xsl/dtd etc.